# Correct BibLaTeX+Biber sorting when the same author published using different given names

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting

In my bibliography I have entries by the same author, published using different given names. Biber (naturally) does not recognize the authors to be the same, and as a result, sorts the entries alphabetically by name. Is there a way to tell Biber that these names are the same, so that it will sort by year instead?

In the following example, the 2000 entry appears before the 1990 one, because "Richard" comes before "Richie". What I want is that the entries are sorted by year instead:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1990,
    author = "Smith, Richie",
    title = "First Entry",
    year = "1990"}
@book{smith2000,
    author = "Smith, Richard",
    title = "Second Entry",
    year = "2000"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{smith1990,smith2000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I know that I can add a `key`:

```
@book{smith1990,
    key = "Smith, Richard, 1990",
@book{smith2000,
    key = "Smith, Richard, 2000",
```

However, I don't know how Biber normally computes the `key`, so I don't know if my format with `lastname, givenname, year` will sort correctly when there are other entries in the bibliography. Furthermore, I would ideally like a solution where I *only* need to specify something in the `smith1990` entry.

Comment: according to your example you are using biblatex + biber and not bibtex, so both your title and your question text and tag are wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer apologies, I have made an edit. I am indeed using biblatex + biber.

Comment: Why not `sortname = {Smith, Richard}`? Then the entry would sort correctly even if you changed the sort order or style globally.

Comment: Related: [biblatex authoryear-comp and name aliases](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/37857)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question Alan Munn linked is relevant, but simply getting the sorting you want can be done, I think, just with `sortname`. The advantage of this is that it only overrides `author` or `editor` when sorting. So if, say, you switch to a different citation or bibliography style, you won't have a hard-coded sort from the bibliography distorting the result. The value of `sortname` will have an effect just when the value of `author` or `editor` would.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1990,
    author = "Smith, Richie",
    sortname = {Smith, Richard},
    title = "First Entry",
    year = "1990"}
@book{smith2000,
    author = "Smith, Richard",
    title = "Second Entry",
    year = "2000"}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{smith1990,smith2000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Richie before Richard in bibliography]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `sortname`, that's very handy.